# improve performance of method using Asyc and await

Tags: c#, devexpress

```
public void Calc()
{
    Method1(true); //Qty*rate 
    Method2(true); //perform another work
    this.Save();
    if (this.Session.InTransaction)         
        this.Session.CommitTransaction();
}
```

I want improve performance using Async and Await

Comment: great, so what's stopping you from doing this?

Comment: what have you tried? are method1 and method2 async (do they return tasks?) this is way to broad...

Comment: You should at least read up on it before posting a question like this. We like to help those who have tried first.

Comment: when i provide Qty and rate, it will take around 0.20 or 0.30 second to calculate extension.

Comment: Is there any dependency between the two methods like for executing Method 2, Method 1 must have finished its job.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about asynchronous committing changes made within a transaction, take a look at the [Session.CommitTransactionAsync](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXpoSession_CommitTransactionAsynctopic) method.

If you are talking about something else you should provide more information or contact the XPO vendor [directly](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).